# Calculus Net change and Indefinite Integrals

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The marginal cost of producting $x$ tablet computers is

$$C'(x) = 110 - 0.04 x + 0.0002\ x^2$$ dollars.

What is the cost of producing $4000$ units if the setup cost is $70000$

Also

If the production is set at $4000$ units, what is the cost of producing $200$ additional units?

I'm not sure exactly what this question is asking, therefore i have no work.

Comment: It wants you to find $C(x)$ with the information that $C(0) = 70000$. Then plug $C(4000)$ for the first question and $C(4200) - C(4000)$ for the second

Comment: So A) Would be $C(4000) + 70000$?

Comment: Nope, just $C(4000)$. You "already add" the fixed costs when you impose $C(0) = 70000$

Comment: Got it, thanks dude.